# update multiple rows in one shot

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-update, where-clause

Consider the following case:

I have three tables: `Student`, `StudentCourse`, `Course`.

`Student` contains info about the student as well as the unique `id` (uuid) which is the primary key.

`Course` contains the unique `id`(uuid) (primary key) of the course and the `name`(text) of the course.

`StudentCourse` keeps track of which courses the student takes by associating a `courseId` (uuid) with the `studentId` (uuid). `courseId` is a FK which references the `id` from `Course` and `studentId` is a FK which references the `id` from `Student`.

Suppose I have the following row in `Student`:

```
id                name
--------------------------
student_id_john  John Doe
```

`Course` (3 rows):

```
id               name
---------------------------
biology_id       Biology
mathematics_id   Mathematics
physics_id       Physics
```

`StudentCourse`(1 row):

```
studentId         courseId
----------------------------
student_id_john   physics_id
```

So currently John Doe takes a Physics class.

I want to update the `StudentCourse` table to reflect a new change: replace "Physics" course with the "Mathematics" course and add a "Biology" course for John Doe.

Suppose I have the following array (the size can vary):

`let course_arr = ["Mathematics", "Biology"]`

I want to update the `StudentCourse` table by:

1. first select the appropriate `id` from `Course` where `name` = "Mathematics" and `name` = "Biology"
2. update the existing row (set `courseId` = `mathematics_id` in `StudentCourse` where `studentId` = `student_id_john`
3. insert a new row: `studentId` = `student_id_john` and `courseId` = `biology_id`

Is there a way to do all of this in one query? I want to access my database only once. I am trying to avoid several calls to the database.

I tried the following query (replace the Physics course with the Mathematics course) but it doesn't work:

```
update student_course 
set "courseId"  = subquery.id
from (select id from course where name = 'Mathematics') as subquery
where "studentId" = student_id_john
```

Comment: I would probably simply delete all rows in `student_course` for that user, then insert the two (new) courses

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist in doing it with a single statement:

```
WITH new_courses AS (
   SELECT '["Mathematics", "Biology"]'::jsonb AS values
), remove AS (
   DELETE FROM student_course
   USING course, new_courses
   WHERE student_course."courseId" = course.id
     AND student_course."studentId" = student_id_john
     AND NOT (to_jsonb(course.name) <@ new_courses.values)
)
INSERT INTO student_course ("studentId", "courseId")
SELECT student_id_john, course.id
FROM course
WHERE to_jsonb(course.name) <@ new_courses.values;
```